# apache 404 error

Tags: fedora, apache-httpd, apache-virtualhost

I installed Fedora 24 and I am trying to set up Apache for virtual host.

I get a "404 Not found" when trying to access via browser.

Below are my config files and error outputs from `httpd -S` (files may have to much in them at this point).

SElinux has been disabled.

`httpd -S` output:

```
AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [/home/www/apecenergy.co.uk/public_html] does not exist
AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [/home/www/rangayoga.co.uk/public_html] does not exist
VirtualHost configuration:
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server www.apecenergy.co.uk (/etc/httpd/conf.d/httpd-vhosts.conf:23)
         port 80 namevhost www.apecenergy.co.uk (/etc/httpd/conf.d/httpd-vhosts.conf:23)
                 alias www.apecenergy.co.uk
         port 80 namevhost rangayoga.co.uk (/etc/httpd/conf.d/httpd-vhosts.conf:32)
                 alias www.rangayoga.co.uk
ServerRoot: "/etc/httpd"
Main DocumentRoot: "/home/david/www"
Main ErrorLog: "/etc/httpd/logs/error_log"
Mutex proxy-balancer-shm: using_defaults
Mutex rewrite-map: using_defaults
Mutex authdigest-client: using_defaults
Mutex lua-ivm-shm: using_defaults
Mutex proxy: using_defaults
Mutex authn-socache: using_defaults
Mutex default: dir="/run/httpd/" mechanism=default 
Mutex mpm-accept: using_defaults
Mutex cache-socache: using_defaults
Mutex authdigest-opaque: using_defaults
PidFile: "/run/httpd/httpd.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="apache" id=48
Group: name="apache" id=48
```

!!!!((( Should the document root be owned by "apache" and not "david", just noticed this now from seeing the last 2 lines)))!!!!

**etc/hosts file:**

```
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6

127.0.0.1  rangayoga.co.uk www.rangayoga.co.uk
127.0.0.1  apecenergy.co.uk www.apecenergy.co.uk
```

**etc/httpd/conf.d/httpd-vhosts.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@apecenergy
    DocumentRoot /home/www/apecenergy.co.uk/public_html
    ServerName www.apecenergy.co.uk
    ServerAlias www.apecenergy.co.uk
    ErrorLog "/var/log/httpd/apecenergy-error_log"
    CustomLog "/var/log/httpd/apecenergy-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@rangayoga.co.uk
    DocumentRoot "/home/www/rangayoga.co.uk/public_html"
    ServerName rangayoga.co.uk
    ServerAlias www.rangayoga.co.uk
    ErrorLog "/var/log/httpd/rangayoga.co.uk-error_log"
    CustomLog "/var/log/httpd/rangayoga.co.uk-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>

ServerName 127.0.0.1
```

**etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf**
(selected data, if you require full document please ask)

```
ServerRoot "/etc/httpd"

#
# Listen: Allows you to bind Apache to specific IP addresses and/or
# ports, instead of the default. See also the <VirtualHost>
# directive.
#
# Change this to Listen on specific IP addresses as shown below to 
# prevent Apache from glomming onto all bound IP addresses.
#
#Listen 12.34.56.78:80
Listen 80

#
# Dynamic Shared Object (DSO) Support
#
# To be able to use the functionality of a module which was built as a DSO you
# have to place corresponding `LoadModule' lines at this location so the
# directives contained in it are actually available _before_ they are used.
# Statically compiled modules (those listed by `httpd -l') do not need
# to be loaded here.
#
# Example:
# LoadModule foo_module modules/mod_foo.so
#
Include conf.modules.d/*.conf

#
# If you wish httpd to run as a different user or group, you must run
# httpd as root initially and it will switch.  
#
# User/Group: The name (or #number) of the user/group to run httpd as.
# It is usually good practice to create a dedicated user and group for
# running httpd, as with most system services.
#
User apache
Group apache

# 'Main' server configuration
#
# The directives in this section set up the values used by the 'main'
# server, which responds to any requests that aren't handled by a
# <VirtualHost> definition.  These values also provide defaults for
# any <VirtualHost> containers you may define later in the file.
#
# All of these directives may appear inside <VirtualHost> containers,
# in which case these default settings will be overridden for the
# virtual host being defined.
#

#
# ServerAdmin: Your address, where problems with the server should be
# e-mailed.  This address appears on some server-generated pages, such
# as error documents.  e.g. admin@your-domain.com
#
ServerAdmin root@localhost

#
# ServerName gives the name and port that the server uses to identify itself.
# This can often be determined automatically, but we recommend you specify
# it explicitly to prevent problems during startup.
#
# If your host doesn't have a registered DNS name, enter its IP address here.
#
#ServerName www.example.com:80

#
# Deny access to the entirety of your server's filesystem. You must
# explicitly permit access to web content directories in other 
# <Directory> blocks below.
#
<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all granted
</Directory>

#
# Note that from this point forward you must specifically allow
# particular features to be enabled - so if something's not working as
# you might expect, make sure that you have specifically enabled it
# below.
#

#
# DocumentRoot: The directory out of which you will serve your
# documents. By default, all requests are taken from this directory, but
# symbolic links and aliases may be used to point to other locations.
#
DocumentRoot "/home/david/www"

#
# Relax access to content within /var/www.
#
<Directory "/home/david/www">
    AllowOverride None
    # Allow open access:
    Require all granted
</Directory>

# Further relax access to the default document root:
<Directory "/home/david/www">
    #
    # Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
    # or any combination of:
    #   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
    #
    # Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
    # doesn't give it to you.
    #
    # The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options
    # for more information.
    #
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

    #
    # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
    # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
    #   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
    #
    AllowOverride All

    #
    # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
    #
    Require all granted
</Directory>

#
# DirectoryIndex: sets the file that Apache will serve if a directory
# is requested.
#
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.html
</IfModule>

#
# The following lines prevent .htaccess and .htpasswd files from being 
# viewed by Web clients. 
#
<Files ".ht*">
    Require all denied
</Files>
```

Answer (score 3):

The first two lines of `httpd -S output` are quite explicit indicating that you didn't create the proper directory structure for (`/home/www/apecenergy.co.uk/public_html` and `/home/www/rangayoga.co.uk/public_html`).

This alone is more than enough to get a HTTP 404 error.

Comment: is the ".co.uk" part allowed?

Comment: That structure is quite common:  `/home/www/$fullDomainName/public_html`

Comment: i have checked the directory and they are there as stated, each folder in turn spelt the same

Comment: Does the `apache` user have access to them?  You can test it by temporarily giving it a shell in `/etc/passwd`.

Comment: Copy and paste the output of the `pwd` command from both of those subdirectories (the `public_html` ones) as well as the permissions on that folder